# Haskell function composition methods

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, composition

I just started learning Haskell at uni, and while playing around with it, I stumbled upon a problem that I can't seem to grasp.
The following code gives me the desired result:

```
import Data.List
list = ["Hello", "world"]

main = print $ intercalate " something " (reverse (map reverse list))
```

Output:

```
"dlrow something olleH"
```

But I want to write the 'main' function with dots instead of brackets, so it tried:

```
main = print $ intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse list
```

However, this gives me the following errors:

```
test.hs:5:54: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> [[Char]]’
                  with actual type ‘[[Char]]’
    • Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
```

I thought that these dots meant exactly the same as the brackets: function composition. Why do the brackets work, whereas the dots give me a type-related error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets don't mean function composition. They just mean “group this subexpression”. Of course you can *use* them to make a chain of function compositions: the following defines `c` as a composition of the functions `f`, `g` and `h`

```
c x = f (g (h x))
```

This could also be written as:

```
c = f . g . h
```

Thus, you *could* write

```
main = print $ c list
 where c = intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse
```

But if you then inline `c` again, you need to be careful not to mess up the parsing rules: just writing `list` to the right of that composition chain will not do, because function application binds more tightly than any infix operator (including `.`, though that is in fact the tightest infix operator). I.e.,

```
intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse list
```

is actually parsed as

```
(intercalate " something ") . (reverse) . (map reverse list)
```

But that's not what you wanted. You need to make sure that `list` is actually the argument to the entire composition chain, not just its last element; the preferred way to do that is with the `$` operator:

```
intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse $ list
```

`$` has the *lowest* prevedence, thus this is parsed as

```
((intercalate " something ") . (reverse) . (map reverse)) (list)
```

Alternatively, you can apply `map reverse` to `list` right away – this by itself isn't wrong, just the result isn't part of the composition chain anymore:

```
intercalate " something " . reverse $ map reverse list
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalence of function composition goes as follows:

```
main = print (intercalate " something " (reverse (map reverse list)))
main = print (intercalate " something " ((reverse . map reverse) list))
main = print ((intercalate " something " . (reverse . map reverse)) list)
main = (print . (intercalate " something " . (reverse . map reverse))) list
```

or, by dropping the unnecessary parentheses:

```
main = (print . intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse) list
main = print . intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse $ list
```

In your attempt, `map reverse list` is a single expression, the argument of the infix `.` operator, which doesn't work - you only can compose the `map reverse` function, and then apply the whole composed function to the `list` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi for your reply, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

Function composition using `.` implies that there will be another parameter to the function. Had you instead written the following, it would work.

```haskell
main = print $ (intercalate " something " . reverse . map reverse) list
```

That way, the `list` value is a parameter to the function composed inside parentheses.

Comment: that actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!